# Confirmation Box : OK button not working after clicking on Cancel Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net

I have a javascript function with a confirmation Box. which is called on a button click. when i click on button, Confirmation Box with OK and Cancel buttons appears. If i click on OK first , then its working fine. But when I click on Cancel and then repopulate the Confirmation box and click OK then it s not working.

**JavaScript**

```
function Confirm() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "Yes";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

**Button**

```
  <asp:Button ID="BtnCancelBooking" runat="server" Text="Cancel My Application" style="background-color:#5A105A;color:#ffffff" 
CssClass="FormsubmitButton" OnClientClick = "Confirm()"
  Width="140px" ValidationGroup="" Visible="True" />
```

**VB Code:**

```
 Protected Sub BtnCancelBooking_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCancelBooking.Click

    Dim confirmValue As String = Request.Form("confirm_value")
    If confirmValue = "Yes" Then


        Dim b As Boolean = objClsRoomBooking.CancelBooking(Convert.ToInt32(Session("AppID")), Convert.ToInt32(Session("StdYearID")), Convert.ToInt32(Session("ComID")))
        If b = True Then
            'ShowMessages(1, "Your Application has been Cancelled ")
            Response.Redirect("Details.aspx")
        Else
            ShowMessages(2, "Applicant Status has not been Cancelled")
        End If

    Else
          // else 
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is appending duplicate hidden elements to the form every time when you re-populate the confirm-box, change your function to this,

```
    function Confirm() {
        var tmpResp = "";
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel?")) {
            tmpResp = "Yes";
        } else {
            tmpResp = "No";
        }
        if(document.getElementById("confirm_value")) {
           document.getElementById("confirm_value").value = tmpResp;
        }
        else {
           var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
           confirm_value.type = "hidden";
           confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
           confirm_value.id = "confirm_value";
           confirm_value.value= tmpResp;
           document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
        }
    }
```

This code checks if `hidden-field` is already exits, if yes then assigns the `confirm-box` response to it otherwise creates new `hidden-field` and appends to `form`.
Hope it helps.